# Shell: Ping a host and Output a Custom "Message"

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i need to write a linux script that pings a host in a timed intervall and doesnt output the standard ping command stuff.

like:

```
ping -i 10 google.com

Output1: google.com POSITIVE
or
Output2: google.com NEGATIVE
```

How can i achieve that it doesnt show the Ping Output and transform that into the Output in the examples?

Thought about using the Returncode if 0 then its positive else negative.

Thanks for help !

Comment: "Thought about using the Returncode if 0 then its positive else negative." Sound like a good plan! What did you try? What didn't work? Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to as a [mre]

Comment: I think the return code part isnt that of a problem but how do i not put out the normal ping command stuff ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, your ping command will run infinitely and so you will need to add a count through -c e.g.:

```
ping -c 2 -i 10 google.com
```

This will ping twice at 10 second intervals.

With this you can then implement:

```
ping -q -c 2 -i 10 google.com && echo "google.com POSITIVE" || echo "google.com NEGATIVE"
```

Anything after && will be executed with a return code of 0 otherwise anything after || will be executed

An alternate if else approach:

```
if ping -q -c 2 -i 10 google.com
then
  echo "google.com POSITIVE"
else
  echo "google.com NEGATIVE"
fi
```

Comment: Well thanks thats working almost like i need it to but i wanted to do it partly myself. Well now i safed time Thanks !

Comment: Your oneliner suggestion is will execute the OR clause, if the "POSITIVE" echo fails. In your example it will not, as echo should not fail. But it's never the less a bad pattern to advocate.

Comment: Fair point but in this particular instance, it is unlikely the echo statement will fail as we are not expanding any variables.